# Vimeo Player JS error when creating player

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm attempting to create a Vimeo embed using player JS `<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>`.

In my php file(wordpress project) I have:

```
<?php 
  $id = get_field('video');
  /* unrelated variables */
?>
<div class="page-single">
  <?php if ($id) : ?>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="video__wrapper">
        <div class="js-video-player video__player" id="video" data-vimeo-id="<?= $id; ?>"></div>
        <img class="js-video-cover video__cover" src="<?= $cover; ?>" />
        <div class="button__wrapper">
        <button class="button__play js-video-btn">Play</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

That's working fine and not necessarily the issue here, so I have the `player.js` being referenced in my `head`. And then in my js file,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  var $video = $('.js-video-player'),
      video_id = $video.data('vimeo-id'),
      $video_poster = $('.js-video-cover'),
      $video_btn = $('.js-video-btn'),
      options = {
        id: video_id
      };
  var player = new Vimeo.Player($video, options);
});
```

Following this, I'm getting an error:

`GET https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F285211306&domain={url}&id={video_id} 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: “https://vimeo.com/{video_id}” was not found.
    at XMLHttpRequest.r.onload (player.js?ver=1:2)`

If any one has any insights as to what I'm doing incorrectly, I don't think I'm doing anything radically difficult but I've been hitting this wall for a little bit now and I'm just confused as to why I'm running into this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: actually you don't have to pass `$` in the ready function handler. Can you remove just give `()` and check if the error goes away ?

Comment: @82Tuskers same error unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get the same error with a public video from Vimeo? The video specified in the error message at vimeo.com/285211306 appears to be private or non-existent. (hence the 404). oEmbed can only be used with embeddable videos that do not have "Only me" viewing privacy.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. @TommyPenner, thank you. It seems my code is working totally fine and it's erring because exactly as you mentioned, it's a private video. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. 404 is not found. Thanks @TommyPenner.  Nice one.

Comment: A classic case of staring at something for too long. Thank you again @TommyPenner.

Comment: You're welcome!! It's a Friday. We've all been there.